# Android notification doesn't disappear after clicking the notification

Tags: android, notifications

If got some issues with a notification I want to show in the notification bar. Although I set the notification flag to `Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS & Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL` the notification doesn't disappear after clicking it. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```java
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

int icon = R.drawable.icon;
CharSequence tickerText = "Ticker Text";
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, time);
notification.flags = Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS & Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL; 

Context context = getApplicationContext();
CharSequence contentTitle = "Title";
CharSequence contentText = "Text";
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, SilentFlipConfiguration.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
mNotificationManager.notify(1,notification);
```

Answer (score 319, accepted):

While building `Notification` by `NotificationBuilder` you can use `notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);`.

Comment: So, what differences create notification using Notification `mNotificationManager.notify(1,notification);` and using NotificationBuilder `mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());`? Thanks.

Comment: This answer should be accepted, it's more in-line with current android design doctrine

Comment: This answer is correct. Accepted one works but not always. There is problem when there are stacked notifications on GCM (or whatever you are using). Once you ping notification server it returns with a lot notifications and sometimes it just loops the notification appearance.

Comment: `notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);` is not working for me. Should I put before my Pending Intent?

Answer (score 131):

```
notification.flags = Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL
```

From the documentation:

> Bit to be bitwise-**or**ed into the flags field that should be set
>   if the notification should be canceled when it is clicked by the user

Comment: This is not the correct answer. `Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS` is part of the `Notification.defaults` class, not the `Notification.flags` class. See my answer for the appropriate setters.

Comment: notification.flags = Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL; this method is working thank you synic.

Comment: The code in this answer resulted in the notification sound being played multiple times. Check out the other answers.

Answer (score 27):

```
// Uses the default lighting scheme
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;

// Will show lights and make the notification disappear when the presses it
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL | Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
```

Comment: I have gone through the android docs. I don't quite get when flags should be used. Why isn't just notification.defaults=notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS enough to show the lights. Because the vibrate and sound work without the flag.

Comment: Am using the NotificationBuilder, NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_popup_sync)
                        .setContentTitle("New Tweet")
                        .setContentText("There are " + count + " tweets"); mBuilder.setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL);

Answer (score 14):

2016 state: you can use `mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)`.

Source: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html

Answer (score 3):

The answer for me was to use `mBuilder.setOngoing(false)`

Answer (score 1):

Use the flag Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL

```
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, pendingIntent);

// Cancel the notification after its selected
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

and to launch the app:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

Intent intent = new Intent(context, App.class);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, intent_id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Answer (score 1):

### **Remove a notification**

Notifications remain visible until one of the following happens:

1. The user dismisses the notification.
2. The user clicks the notification, and you called setAutoCancel() when you created the notification.
3. You call cancel() for a specific notification ID. This method also deletes ongoing notifications.
4. You call cancelAll(), which removes all of the notifications you previously issued.
5. If you set a timeout when creating a notification using setTimeoutAfter(), the system cancels the notification after the specified duration elapses. If required, you can cancel a notification before the specified timeout duration elapses.

For more details see: 
https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification?hl=en