# Android notification FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL not working and not showing new Activity

Tags: android, android-notifications

I've been searching for almost a day for this problem, I followed the example about Android Notification here: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidNotifications/article.html. It worked well and I can send the `Notification`. The problem is, when I click on the notification, it does NOT disappear even though I have set:

`setAutoCancel(true)` AND `notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL`

**Update: Here is my code**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MyNotification.this, NotificationReceiver.class);

PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
    MyNotification.this, 0, intent, 0);

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = 
     new NotificationCompat.Builder(MyNotification.this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Call", pIntent)
    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "More", pIntent)
    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "And more", pIntent)
    .setContentTitle("New mail from " + "test@gmail.com")
    .setContentText("Subject");

Notification noti = builder.build();
noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
NotificationManager notificationManager = 
    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
```

Any ideas where the problem come from? Thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 5):

Use this:

> ```
> notification.flags = Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL
> ```

Source: [@synic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/238849/synic)'s answer to [Android notification doesn't disappear after clicking the notification](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2632341/4108803)

Answer (score 1):

Try removing:

```
noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

It should work without noti.flags.

The new way of using flags in NotificationCompat is to use the defined methods, like setAutoCancel(true).